# Existence and uniqueness of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing my first ODE course, and I have a couple of questions that came to mind when practicing some problems.

1. My question is about ODEs with an initial condition y(0) = 0 for equations such as $ y'(x) = (3/2)y(x)^{1/3}$? My understanding is that differential equations are defined in open sets around some given point. So, if we consider a potential solution, such as $y(x) = x^{3/2}$, for any open set around x = 0 we'd be containing negative values. So would this be a solution to the ODE? Or would the lack of a defined open set around the point prevent this.
2. I've also been taught that Lipschitz Continuity guarantees the existence of unique solutions, but I'm struggling to understand the Picard-Lindelof theorem a bit. Does it tell us that there exists a locally unique solution centered around for any IVP provided the function is Lipschitz Continuous on some closed set around the $x_0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret $y^{1/3}$ as the real valued cube root function with $(-y)^{1/3}=-y^{1/3}$, then the right side has an unrestricted domain and is continuous in $x$ and $y$.

The Peano theorem states that for a continuous right side local solutions exist. No guarantee for uniqueness is made, and examples like this one show that IVP can have multiple solutions.

The Picard-Lindelöf theorem adds the uniqueness under the condition that the right side is locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$. You have to show that this is given here except on the line $y=0$. So you get uniqueness as long as the solution remains inside the upper or lower half-plane

You can also confirm that $y(x)=0$ unrestricted and $y(x)=-x^{3/2}$ for $x\ge 0$ are solutions. You can patch them together, $y(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $y(x)=\pm x^{3/2}$ for $x\ge 0$. You can then also shift such a solution to the right, and it will still be a solution of the IVP.